# Switch branch name on SourceTree

Tags: git, version-control, atlassian-sourcetree

I was learning how to use SourceTree and git, and after experimenting I accidentally made a commit in the wrong branch, and it seems like my `master` branch is no longer the main branch.

[image: Picture of my SourceTree graph]

Here is an image of what my graph currently looks like. 
I was wondering it is possible for me somehow make `bugfix-z` branch my `master` branch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering `master` has been merged into `bugfix-z`, a consider simple

```
git checkout master
git merge bugfix-z
```

That would fast-forward `master` to `bugfix-z` HEAD.

Comment: @Sachin yes, or you can checkout the master branch in source tree, and merge bugfix-z in SourceTree: same result

Comment: Thanks, I have fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't pushed yet, you can easily [revert the last commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/how-do-you-undo-the-last-commit) using

```
git reset --soft HEAD~1
```

You can type in this command in the terminal (use the 'terminal' button on the right of the toolbar).
[image]

After that you can switch to the master branch and commit the changes again.

Comment: In the terminal. You will find a terminal button on the right of the SourceTree toolbar. Button icon looks like `>_`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have fixed the issue.